# Lookup with duplicate values

Tags: sql, join, lookup

This is kind of a complicated question. I have three tables:

A PRODUCTS table

| ProductID | ProductName |
| --- | --- |
| Product A | Edwardian Desk |
| Product B | Edwardian Lamp |

And a GROUPS table

| ProductGroup | ProductID |
| --- | --- |
| Group A | Product A |
| Group A | Product B |
| Group B | Product C |

And a SALES table

| Product ID | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| Product A | 1000 |
| Product B | 500 |

And I need to show the total of Sales per Product Group.

This part I understand; I wrote the query:

```
SELECT Groups.ProductGroup, SUM(Sales) AS TotalSales
FROM Groups
JOIN Sales
ON Groups.ProductID=Sales.ProductID
GROUP BY Groups.ProductGroup
```

This is the part that confuses me though: for each group, I need to pull in one of the names of the products in the group. However, it does not matter which name is pulled. So the final data could show:

```
Group A, Edwardian Desk, 1500
```

or

```
Group A, Edwardian Lamp, 1500
```

How can I pull the name of the product into my query?

I am working in Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: To get "one of the" without any particular logic you can use `max` or `min` aggregation function. It accepts strings for input

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of ways to bring in one of your product's names, a couple of options are to either use an `aggregation` with a `correlated subquery` or to to use an `apply`.

Note, I've used `aliases` for your table names - doing so is good practice and makes queries more compact and easier to read. Also - presumably this is a contrived example and not your actual tables - but generally it's not a good practice to have column names identical to the table name, so if `Sales` on table `Sales` represents a quantity, then just call it `Quantity`!

```
select g.ProductGroup,
  (select Min(ProductName) from Products p where p.ProductId=g.ProductId) FirstProductAlphabetically,
  Sum(s.Sales) as TotalSales
from Groups g
join Sales s on s.ProductID=g.ProductID
group by g.ProductGroup


select g.ProductGroup, 
  p.ProductName as FirstProductById,
  Sum(s.Sales) as TotalSales
from Groups g
join Sales s on s.ProductID=g.ProductID
cross apply (
    select top (1) p.ProductName
    from Products p
    where p.ProductId=g.ProductId
    order by ProductId
)p
group by g.ProductGroup
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `products` to the `JOIN` and use an aggregation function:

```
SELECT g.ProductGroup, SUM(s.Sales) AS TotalSales,
       MIN(p.ProductName)
FROM Groups g JOIN
     Sales s
     ON g.ProductID = s.ProductID JOIN
     Products p
     ON p.ProductID = s.ProductId
GROUP BY g.ProductGroup;
```

Note:  I often add two columns, `MIN()` and `MAX()` to get two sample names.

I should add.  Your sample data has `ProductId`s that are *not* in the `Products`.  That suggests a problem with either the question (more likely) or the data model.  If you actually have references to non-existent products, then use a `LEFT JOIN` to `Products` rather than an inner join.